# bash script to select .c files in subdirectories

Tags: bash

My problem is slightly weird so bear with me.

In my current path, I have 3 folders named folder1 , folder2 and folder3.

In each folder is a C program implemented over multiple files and subdirectories. **For each folder**, I want to run the command

```
sea <file1.c> <file2.c> ...
```

where <file1.c> , <file2.c> ... are ALL the .c files present in folder 1 or in some subfolder of folder1 or some subfolder of a subfolder of folder1 and so on...

I want to write a bash script to do so.

I create a FOLDERS variable, with:

```
FOLDERS=(folder1 folder2 folder3)
```

I can iterate over each entry in FOLDERS, but my question is how to collect all the .c files of given folder in a new variable like CFILES and then use that variable for a instruction like:

```
sea $(CFILES)
```

for each folder?

Comment: Use a wildcard: `"$folder"/*.c`

Comment: @Barmar Maybe the question wasn't clear, so I give an example. Let folder1 have two subfolders : subfolder1 and subfolder2 which have C files A.c and B.c respectively.
Then the command for folder1 should be sea A.c B.c   . But "$folder"/*.c will return empty because folder1 doesn't have a C file.

Comment: Use the `globstar` feature: `"$folder"/**/*.c`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't.

```
for d in folder[123]; do ( cd $d && sea *.c ); done
```

The only complication I see is if the order of arguments has to be something other than the lexical order this will generate.

If you don't absolutely have to be IN the folder for the code to work, then you don't need the subshell parens.

```
for d in folder[123]; do sea $d/*.c; done
```

If you need all the `*.c` files in all subdirectories, then use `globstar`.

```
shopt -s globstar
for d in folder[123]; do sea $d/**/*.c; done
```

This should limit files processed to those ending in `.c` under one of `folder1 folder2 folder3` but including any subdirectories to any depth.

Or, as above, if you need to run the script directly in the directory with each file:

```
shopt -s globstar
for d in folder[123]/**/; do ( cd $d && sea *.c ); done
```

If your list of directories is not as simple or short as `folder1 folder2 folder3`, an array is best.

```
dirs=( folder[123] otherFolder /some/full/path another/relative/*/path )
```

Then use the same logic as needed.

```
for d in "${dirs[@]}"; do sea $d/**/*.c; done
```

or

```
for d in "${dirs[@]}"/**/; do ( cd $d && sea *.c ); done
```

Just please be sure you understand what each is doing. Feel free to ask questions if you don't.

Comment: If folder1 has a file A.c and a subfolder named subfolder1 which in turn has a C file B.c, then would sea folder1/*.c collect all these files or just A.c?

Comment: Edit: It doesn't work, as it for the above example, it will only return A.c; I need all the C files whose ancestor (not just parent) is folder1.

Comment: That's why you need the `globstar`. When yolu issue `for d in "${dirs[@]}"/**/; do ( cd $d && sea *.c ); done` it will run `sea *,c` in folder1 to get A.c, but then will also run it in each subdirectory *separately*. If you need them all on the command line **IN** folder1, use the `for d in "${dirs[@]}"; do sea $d/**/*.c; done` version, or combine them into `(cd "$d" && sea ./**/*.c)`.

Comment: Yeah, that comment was before you edited your answer to add the globstar.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `globstar` option to allow wildcards to expand recursively.

```
shopt -s globstar
for folder in "${FOLDERS[@]"; do
    sea "$folder"/**/*.c
```